# Dictionary of generic lists or varying types

Tags: c#

I want to have a Dictionary that maps strings to generic lists of varying types. i.e. in the following form:

```
Key        Value
string     List<T>
string     List<U>
string     List<V>
string     List<U>
...
```

Currently I'm using a `Dictionary<string, IList>` and then extracted the strongly typed list from each dictionary `KeyValuePair<string, IList> pair` entry as follows:

```
Type layerType = pair.Value.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
List<layerType> objectsClicked = pair.Value as List<layerType>;
```

Is there a nicer way to do this?

[Edit]
As has been noted, the above doesn't compile, apologies - that's what you get when you ask a question while you're still working on somethings. 
Some more explanation. I'm making a basic spatial data viewer. The final view consists of  a group of `Layer<T>`s.  Each layer provides a delegate to render its type (given an offset and scale) and a way to check which of its objects are in the current window.  For hit testing, I would like a List for each Layer of which objects have been hit. That list would be a `List<Point>` for a `Point` layer, etc... The grouping of the hits from all the `Layer<T>`s would then be a collection of strongly typed lists.

Comment: The provided code-sample won't compile. In any case, it would really help if you could tell us a) what you are going to do with the list once you get it out b) what the bigger problem you are trying to solve is.

Comment: What you have won't compile. You can't pass a type object as a generic type parameter. Why do even need generics if you're not accessing the list in a strongly typed fashion?

Comment: Since you put these lists in the same dictionary, there must be some common grounds between them (e.g. they have the same base class/interface or something). You should provide more information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I Create a Dictionary of Generic Types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654752/can-i-create-a-dictionary-of-generic-types)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

How about `Dictionary<string, dynamic>` assuming you're on C# 4

```
Dictionary<string, dynamic> Dict = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
Dict.Add("int", new List<int>());
Dict.Add("string", new List<string>());

Dict["int"].Add(12);
Dict["string"].Add("str");

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, dynamic> pair in Dict) {
   Type T = pair.Value.GetType();
   Console.WriteLine(T.GetGenericArguments()[0].ToString());
}
```

That prints out

> System.Int32
>
> System.String

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I think his Dictionary<string, IList> is much better. Dont confuse him with dynamic.

Comment: Why the downvote?  This appears to do exactly what he's looking for.

Comment: You could have done the same with a new Dictionary<string, object>() without using dynamics

Comment: Yes, you *could* do it with Dictionary<string, object>, but then you'd have to do a cast *every* time you accessed something inside of your Dictionary so as to manipulate the list.  Plenty of people make a living with dynamic languages, I don't think it will kill anybody to use dynamic typing in C# once in a while when the situation calls for it.  I think some language purists need to calm down a bit

Comment: @Adam - I gave you an upvote, Your solution is fine, but Euphoric hasn't figured out generics yet so I wouldn't try confusing him with dynamics yet.

Comment: I understand generics well, thank you. Problem is C# is static-typed language. dynamic was added into .NET for dynamic languages and added into C# for the "cool" factor. I think dynamic has no place in language like C#, because it provides nothing but adds unncecessary complexity into code.

Comment: Dynamic serves much more than the "cool factor."  It allows for duck-typing, "expando" objects, and simplified reflection.  If you ever make a demeaning comment like that again, I will send Eric Lippert after you...

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to have to play around a bit more, but I think that this is what I need. I don't know at compile time what the type will be so dynamic is the way to go I think.

Answer (score 3):

I am going to take a middleground between Euphoric and Adam, you should make use of both `IList` and `dynamic`. This is what I think is more correct:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, IList>();
dict.Add("u", new List<U>());
dict.Add("v", new List<V>());

// in case of members you know they exist on an IList
dict["u"].Add(new U());
dict["v"].Add(new V());

// in case you know what you are going to get back, in which case you should cast
var uProperty = (dict["u"][0] as U).UProperty
var vProperty = (dict["v"][0] as V).VProperty

// in case your're not sure of     
(dict[someKey] as dynamic)[someIndex].SomeMember...;
```

All these are much simpler than relying on reflection. The basic idea is declare the dictionary value type as `IList` to make your intentions clearer up front, while make use of `dynamic` to ease the reflection monstrosity and make code shorter.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Dictionary<string, IList>` is possibly only solution. But your piece of code is wrong, you cant use generics like that. You cant create type dynamicaly like this.

The general problem with your need is that it is not compatible with strong-typed language like C#. In strong-typed language you must know what type is type EXACTLY. But thi cant be done using normal means. Also your understanding of generics is wrong. Its only compile-time extension to the type.

**And general idea**: In your case, using some kind OOP hiearchy of types that you save in those lists. This will be much better and safer idea and wont make everyone who looks at your code rip his hair out.

Comment: Situations like this where you need flexibility with the type system are *exactly* what dynamic was designed for (among other things, like easier reflection).

Answer (score 0):

I actually think the cleaner approach is to create a wrapper for your dictionary:

```
public class GlobalStore
{
    private readonly IDictionary<Type, IEnumerable> _globalStore;

    public GlobalStore()
    {
        _globalStore = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, IEnumerable>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetFromCache<T>()
        where T : class 
    {
        return (IEnumerable<T>) _globalStore[typeof(T)];
    }

    public void SetCache<T>(IEnumerable<T> cache)
        where T : class
    {
        _globalStore[typeof(T)] = cache;
    }
}
```

Here's a test for it:

```
[TestClass]
public class GlobalStoreTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void GlobalStore_Test()
    {
        //Arrange
        var globalStore = new GlobalStore();
        globalStore.SetCache(new List<ClientModel>
        {
            new ClientModel
            {
                ClientId = 1,
                ClientName = "Client1"
            },
            new ClientModel
            {
                ClientId = 2,
                ClientName = "Client2"
            }
        });

        //Act
        var clients = globalStore.GetFromCache<ClientModel>();

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(2, clients.Count());
    }
}
```