# Remove concrete object dependency from based class

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, base-class

I have inherited code that I need to extend and add some functionality to it.

I have a base class that stores list of concrete objects "OrderA":

```
private List<OrderA> _orders;
```

I want to replace the concrete object implementation with generic one.

So right now I have:

```
/// <summary>
/// This is DataContract that received via a web service
/// </summary>
public class Order
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}

public class OrderA : Order
{
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
}

// Base class
public class WorksheetBase
{
    // Uses concrete OrderA object
    private List<OrderA> _orders;

    public void CreateWorksheet()
    {
        _orders = new List<OrderA>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            var o = new OrderA();
            o.Prop1 = string.Format("Value {0}", i);
            _orders.Add(o);
        }
    }

    public void SaveWorksheets()
    {
        if (_orders == null)
            return;

        foreach (var order in _orders)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(order.Prop1);
        }
    }
}

public class WorksheetA : WorksheetBase
{
    OrderA[] _activeOrders;

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class WorksheetB : WorksheetBase
{
    OrderA[] _activeOrders;

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    public static Dictionary<string, WorksheetBase> dic = new Dictionary<string, WorksheetBase>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WorksheetA fz = new WorksheetA();
        fz.Name = "Work Sheet A";
        fz.CreateWorksheet();
        dic[fz.Name] = fz;

        WorksheetB fwd = new WorksheetB();
        fwd.Name = "Work Sheet B";
        fwd.CreateWorksheet();
        dic[fwd.Name] = fwd;

        SaveWorksheets();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void SaveWorksheets()
    {
        foreach (var item in dic)
        {
            item.Value.SaveWorksheets();
        }
    }
}
```

Now I need to add a new feature for (WorksheetC)

```
public class OrderC : Order
{
    public string Prop4 { get; set; }
}

public class WorksheetC : WorksheetBase
{
    OrderC[] _activeOrders;

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I feel like implementing the generic type parameter  would be the right way to go for this scenario.

```
public class WorksheetBase<T>
{
    private List<T> _orders;

    public void CreateWorksheet()
    {
        _orders = new List<T>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            ....
        }
    }

    public void SaveWorksheets()
    {
        if (_orders == null)
            return;

        foreach (var order in _orders)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(order.Prop1);
        }
    }

}

public class WorksheetA : WorksheetBase<OrderA>
{
    OrderA[] _activeOrders;

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

But I get errors when the dictionary is instantiated:

```
public static Dictionary<string, WorksheetBase> dic = new Dictionary<string, WorksheetBase>();
```

Maybe I'm going about this all wrong, but it's bugging me. Any thoughts on a better way to handle this? I feel like I've got to be missing something simple...

Comment: "*But I get errors when the dictionary is instantiated*", could you also include the error message/code?

Comment: That's expected cause you didn't specify the type parameter `WorksheetBase<T>`.

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/654752/6741868) is related, you would need to specify the type while declaring the dictionary, e.g. `public static Dictionary<string, WorksheetBase<OrderA>> dic = new ...` or perhaps keep separate dictionaries such as `public static Dictionary<string, WorksheetA> dicA`and ``public static Dictionary<string, WorksheetB> dicB``.

Comment: Actually, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5038029/6741868) suggests using `dynamic`. Could you try `public static Dictionary<string, dynamic> dic = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();` and see if that does what you need?

Comment: Your question seems to boil down to: you want to keep a collection of values (dictionary, in this case) where those values are derived from some base class that is generic, but where each value class type uses a different generic type parameter for that base class. As noted in the marked duplicate, that's not possible. You _must_ provide a type parameter for a generic type used in a collection. If you want the same collection to contain types of varying generic type parameters, you'll need some other common type. ...

Comment: ... E.g. a non-generic `WorksheetBase` type which the generic `WorksheetBase<T>` type inherits, or just plain `System.Object`, etc. Of course, in doing so, you'll need to adjust the division of duties to preserve the polymorphic behavior you had previously. For example, make `SaveWorksheets()` an abstract method, implemented by the generic subclass `WorksheetBase<T>`, where the type of the `_orders` collection is known.

Comment: FWIW, in addition to the marked duplicate, there are many other similar questions already on Stack Overflow, all involving this idea of trying to use a generic type as a type parameter for a generic collection, but where the instances will have different type parameters for that generic type, and the answer always is the same: the parameterized generic type isn't a common base class for the different subclass types used, and so won't work. You need to find or create a separate base class that _can_ be common to all the specific subclass types used.