# Cannot convert generic object

Tags: c#

The following does not compile on line fm.AddFoo(new StringFoo()); with the error message:

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ClassLibrary2.StringFoo' to 'ClassLibrary2.IFoo'

This seems logical to me since string inherits from object.

```
public interface IFoo<T>
{
    void Handle(T value);
}

public class StringFoo : IFoo<string>
{
    public void Handle(string value)
    { }
}

public class ObjectFoo : IFoo<object>
{
    public void Handle(object value)
    { }
}

public class FooManager
{
    private readonly List<IFoo<object>> _foos;

    public FooManager()
    {
        _foos = new List<IFoo<object>>();
    }

    public void AddFoo(IFoo<object> foo)
    {
        _foos.Add(foo);
    }
}

public class Bad
{
    public Bad()
    {
        var fm = new FooManager();

        fm.AddFoo(new StringFoo()); \\ This does not compile
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I Create a Dictionary of Generic Types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654752/can-i-create-a-dictionary-of-generic-types)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it may seem like IFoo is a subclass of IFoo it is not. When you close IFoo<> to a specific type is is not creating a subclass of IFoo from IFoo, they are seperate and distinct types with no common hierarchy.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot all about that. Thanks!

Comment: To be explicit, an `IFoo<string>` is not an `IFoo<object>` in the above code. For that to happen would require `IFoo` to be covariant, but its member `Handle` goes in the opposite direction. See my new answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you could make your `IFoo<>` interface ***covariant*** it would work, that is if you were allowed to change the declaration of it into:

```
public interface IFoo<out T>
```

(note the `out`). Because with covariance any `IFoo<string>` would also be an `IFoo<object>` because `string` is a reference type and derives from `object`.

***But:*** A member of `IFoo<>`, the `Handle` method, uses the type parameter in a contravariant manner. So your interface cannot be declared covariant (`out`). (It could be declared contravariant (`in`) but that goes in the wrong direction for your example above.)

Read up on covariance and contravariance in generics.

The fundamental problem here is that your `StringFoo` handles only strings. Therefore it can never be used as an `IFoo<object>` because then you could pass for example a `Giraffe` instance (`Giraffe` derives from `object`, so a `Giraffe` is an `object`) into the `StringFoo`, and that is impossible when its `Handle` takes a `string`.